# VBA code that skips a row instead of "For Each row In rng.Rows"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

hope anyone can help me with my VBA code.

It now says:
If cell.Value = "ja" And (cell.Offset(0, 9) = "meenemen") Then...

I would like it to be something like: If cell.Value = "ja" And (cell.Offset(0, 9) = "meenemen") or ((cell.Offset(1, 0) = "ja" and (cell.Offset(1, 9) = "meenemen")) Then...

I now use: For Each row In rng.Rows
But I would like it to ONLY check every other row (and in another part of my coding every 6 th row) before proceding.

Unfortunately I cannot change the layout of the worksheet where the data is loaded in.

Does anyone has a nice solution for me? Thanks in advance for your effort to help me.

The part of the VBA code it concerns looks like this now:

Sub CheckRange3()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("C47:C66")

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell In row.Cells
    If cell.Value = "ja" And (cell.Offset(0, 9) = "meenemen") Then

```
    Dim Name As String
    DateStr = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy")
    Name = cell.Offset(0, -1).Text & "-" & Range("A44") & " " & DateStr
    cell.Offset(0, 12).Value = Name

    Dim startPath As String
    Dim myName As String

    startPath = "I:\Medische Microbiologie\Virologie\Sequence-resultaten\@In bewerking\"
    myName = cell.Offset(0, 12).Text       ' Change as required to cell holding the folder title

    If myName = vbNullString Then myName = "Testing"

    Dim folderPathWithName As String
    folderPathWithName = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName

    If Dir(folderPathWithName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        MkDir folderPathWithName
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
       'Delete files
        FSO.deletefile MyPath & "\*.*", False
        'Delete subfolders
        FSO.deletefolder MyPath & "\*.*", False
        On Error GoTo 0

    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BLAST resultaten LSU-ITS").Range("F6").Value = cell.Offset(0, 6).Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BLAST resultaten LSU-ITS").Range("A10").Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BLAST resultaten LSU-ITS").Range("B10").Value = cell.Offset(0, 7).Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BLAST resultaten LSU-ITS").Range("C10").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BLAST resultaten LSU-ITS").Range("E10").Value = cell.Offset(0, 4).Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BLAST resultaten LSU-ITS").Range("F10").Value = cell.Offset(0, 5).Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BLAST resultaten LSU-ITS").Range("G10").Value = cell.Offset(0, 8).Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BLAST resultaten LSU-ITS").Range("E11").Value = cell.Offset(1, 4).Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BLAST resultaten LSU-ITS").Range("F11").Value = cell.Offset(1, 5).Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BLAST resultaten LSU-ITS").Range("G11").Value = cell.Offset(1, 8).Text

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BLAST resultaten LSU-ITS").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (startPath & myName & "\BLAST resultaten " & Name)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

Else
    cell.Offset(0, 12).ClearContents
End If
```

Next cell
Next row

'FolderInBewerking

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `For Next` loop and the `Step` keyword to specify an increment.

```
Dim rowIterator As Long
For rowIterator = 1 To rng.Rows.Count Step 2 ' Will go through every other row from the first to the last (or last-1 depending on parity of your number of rows)
    Set row = rng.Rows(rowIterator)
    ' Your code
Next rowIterator
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I added your code and changed If cell.Value = "ja" And (cell.Offset(0, 9) = "meenemen") Then... to
If cell.Value = "ja" And (cell.Offset(0, 9) = "meenemen") Or
(cell.Offset(1, 9) = "meenemen") Then...     and now it works like a charm. Perfect, thank you verg much!